# What is suitable Xcode for 10.6.8?

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Can anybody tell me that what is suitable Xcode version for 10.6.8(snow leopard)?Does Xcode 4.2 installed on it?

Comment: Are you asking what the lowest version is that will run or are you asking in general? If in general, then 4.2 is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install Xcode 4.2 on Mac OS 10.6.8.
Xcode 4.3 is only supported in Max OS Lion.

Comment: Although you probably want 4.2.1, not the original 4.2. Besides the fact that you generally want the latest patch release, in this case, many of the new changes in 4.2 were buggy (e.g., "convert to ARC" would often just hang forever, trying to add iCloud entitlements to an existing project sometimes failed, …) until 4.2.1

Answer (score 0):

No, Xcode 4.2.1 will not install with OS X 10.6.8! I followed the advice above and spent hours downloading only to find that 10.7 is required to install!